# animate an element to fullscreen with css

Tags: html, css, animation, fullscreen

How do I animate a  to expand to fit the screen upon clicking. I do not want to give a position in the initial state. Div should be able to be used dynamically within the screen.

```
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.fullscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Codepen demo of my code](http://codepen.io/ahmetkuslular/pen/vYOGQGe)

Comment: can u plz send ur code or add ur code in codepen?

Comment: So what is your question ?, How to add class `.fullscreen` to element ?, Use javascript to toggle class [Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class)

Comment: Your Question is a bit unclear. Please Clarify your need and put the code that you have done to get help from others.

Comment: I want to make fullScreen when a box is clicked. However, the box can be used anywhere in the screen. so its location is unclear. So I can't give a position.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link to your site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) or any other third party site.

Answer (score 1):

In order to animate the `left` and `top` you'll need an initial value, which you don't have. You can add them upon click and then set the new values by changing the class.

Note that I added the new values in the style so we also need to add `!important` to the class rule so it will override the inline style.

```js
function expand(){
  // get the element
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
  
  // set top and left properties
  box.style.setProperty("left", box.offsetLeft + "px");
  box.style.setProperty("top", box.offsetTop + "px");
  box.style.setProperty("position", "absolute");
  
  // now change the class for the animation will work
  box.className = "fullscreen";
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.fullscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onClick="expand()"></div>
```

Comment: the problem is not in the click script, but in animation. I guess you didn't understand my question.

Comment: I fixed my answer, if I undetstood right, you want the animation to start from the current place and not from "0,0"

Comment: exactly, you understood my question but the animation does not work properly. Going directly to the top.

Comment: Related to my example - I added margin-top as initial value, and it works

Comment: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ahmetkuslular/pen/vYOGQGe) can you try it here I did not get the same result. I'm using react, I just changed the class instead of using setProperty.

Comment: You added a padding of 100px, it stays in the fullscreen as well. Remove the padding from the container and add `margin: 100px;` to your `.box`

Comment: No, that's an example. It is not clear where and how to use the internal component. it must be dynamic. The screen should be able to work anywhere.

Comment: But you defined a padding to your element - it applies also in the fullscreen mode. It's not related to the animation, the end result will have padding anyway in your example. The animation only takes you from the starting point to the end point - if both have padding then you have a different problem...

Comment: yes, you are right, but how can i make this a dynamic structure. Header or footer can be used. that is, I do not know the right to use.

Comment: Now you're asking how to layout your site, that's a different question, it's complex and depends on your requirements....

Comment: No, I want to make a dynamic component independent of its location. https://codesandbox.io/s/8130rn9q2 you can review it. I want to do this with css. ://